# Warning: Attempt to present ChooseLevelViewController on level1ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

i have a `level1ViewController` and a `ChooselevelViewController`. if the game ends in `level1VC`, this method is called:

```
-(void) checkGameFinished {
if ([self.gameModel isGameOver]) {


            self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LEVEL COMPLETED!"];



    double delayTimeInSeconds = 3.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTimeDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTimeInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTimeDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //code to be executed after delay

    [progressBarTimer invalidate];

        ChooseLevelViewController *clvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chooseLevelViewController"];

        clvc.level1Completed = 1;


        [self.finishAudio play];

        [self presentViewController:clvc animated:NO completion:^(){
            [self.gameModel clearGameData];

        }];
          });//code to be executed after delay end
}
}
```

i get the following warning, when my chooseLevelVC appeared:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

And my `progressbarTimer`, doesn't work. The `progressbarTimer` count 20secs down with a `progressBar`. Works fine if i start the game and choose my Level. but it doesn't works when i come from my level1VC.

whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Who is calling `checkGameFinished`?

Comment: the `level1VC` is `calling checkgameFinished`, and present `chooseLevelViewController`

Answer (score 0):

At the time of calling `checkGameFinished`, `level1VC` is probably not visible anymore. The level ends, then you are sending a delayed message to `level1VC`to present `chooseLevelViewController`, but after time passes and the method runs, `level1VC` was already removed from the window.

delaying the call is the culprit it seems. you should call the dismissViewController after the timer ends, and add the other logic in the dismiss's completion block.

Comment: i tried your answer now, and deleted the delay, but the problem is still there.

Comment: When is `level1VC` being dismissed?, as in, can you update the question with the code?

Comment: i havent a dismiss method for level1VC, that what I've posted is all i have for changing the viewcontroller